# Firebase Crashlytics with Swift Package Manager - crash because of wrong path

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have installed Firebase through the Swift Package Manager for my iOS project, including Crashlytics. I have followed these instructions and added the required script to build phases:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

So the path for execution is:
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

On start up (iPhone simulator), the app crashes with the following error message:

*/Users/**[path-to-my-project]**/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run: No such file or directory Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code*

I don't understand why it tries to find the crashlytics script in my Xcode project folder and not in the derived data folder at runtime.

I checked the derived data folder and followed the path. Indeed, the Crashlytics run script is at the expected path.

thanks for any hints in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I've found out that the path to the build folder is set globally in the Xcode preferences. For some reason I don't recall, my build folder has always been in my project folder for all projects I ever worked on in Xcode... I know this for sure because I always add the build folder to .gitignore.
To change the build folder to be a subfolder of your project's derived data folder, go to:
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Advanced and select the first option.
Firebase assumes that this option is selected by default (maybe it is and I'm the weirdo...).
[image]

Comment: If you are a weirdo, then so am I. Your answer saved me :)